# Okta synchronization with Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, okta, okta-api

We want to use OKTA for SSO but need to know if this is Synced in both ways? 
In case if we are making any change in Salesforce side for User , will this be updated back to OKTA, believe not and this would need API calls. 
Someone Please confirm.
Pls share the OKTA API wsdl or Link for Salesforce call outs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, ultimately something has the be the master of a Users profile. Okta can push almost any record to salesforce, no problem, and it can import changes from salesforce. But, which source is authoritative ?

What I have done in the past, is I used a (I'm not a salesforce admin) trigger, so when a Users profile was updated in Salesforce, it would make a web service call to update elements of that users profile that needed to be immediately sync'd with Okta.

In this situation, there were people in a call center, and if someone updated their subscription service, they needed that to get pushed to Okta immediately so they could have Okta update that users profile in other downstream systems.

Okta uses rest, not WSDL, but you can easily build a proxy service to accept them, and convert them in to JSON Rest calls. Everything you need is available on https://developer.okta.com (including a sandbox if you need it).

There is also a postman collection, so you can get familiar with the Okta APIs. Here is the link to that: https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/api_test_client